# spring security call idm every n minute instead of everytime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, identity-management

using spring boot and spring security i was tasked to implements a mechanism that will call the Identity Manager every time that a method of the frontend is called.However some concern popped up: we are afraid to overload the idm with too many request.So i was thinking if there is a way to check for the token not for every call but instead every time interval.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${antPatterns}")
    private String antPatterns;

    @Value("${statistiche.security.enabled:true}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor() {
        return new AuthoritiesSSOExtractor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PrincipalSSOExtractor principalExtractor() {
        return new PrincipalSSOExtractor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //PRODUZIONE
        if(securityEnabled) {
            http.anonymous().disable()
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers(antPatterns)
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(antPatterns).authenticated()
                    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
        }
        else
        {
            http.anonymous().disable().antMatcher(antPatterns).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "statistiche.security.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Value("${antPatterns}")
    private String antPatterns;

    @Value("${statistiche.security.enabled:true}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**").and().ignoring().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        //http.antMatcher(antPatterns).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        if(securityEnabled)
        {
            http
                    .anonymous().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(antPatterns).authenticated()
                    .and()//.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        }else{
            http.antMatcher(antPatterns).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
            //http.antMatcher(antPatterns).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return  new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just informing you that caching tokens is a security risk, so that you are aware of it.

Comment: Indeed you're right.But we need to think about a trade-off between chaching and avoid overwhelm identity manager with request.

Comment: An approach could be keep track of the last activity of the session related to the token. If the last activity time has been before the threshold a request to the identity manager will be send to check if the token is still valid. My problem is that i don't know (and i couldn't find a way) to put this check before the framework call the identity manager.